# ¿Cómo seleccionar el elemento anterior a otro con CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3

Saludos

Estoy tratando de aplicar un estilo a un elemento después de que un elemento hermano adquiera una clase, estaba utilizando el selector adyacente así.

`select.valid + label{..}`

y el HTML así.

```
<div>
  <select>..</select>
  <label>..</label>
</div>
```

Pero esto solo funciona si el ***label*** va precedido del ***select*** con la clase ***.valid***. lo que no logro es hacer lo contrario es decir si tengo esto.

```
<div>
  <label>..</label>
  <select>..</select>      
</div>
```

Aplicar un estilo al ***label*** cuando el ***select*** tenga la clase ***.valid***

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Con CSS no es posible, no puedes ir hacia atrás en el HTML. Tendrías que hacerlo con javascript

Comment: Puedes poner una clase o un id al label o al div? Entonces el css será sencillo, sino hazlo con javascript como dice @blonfu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realmente no hay ningún selector que te permita seleccionar el elemento anterior a otro. Sin embargo, puedes poner el `HTML` tal y como lo tienes en tu pregunta (con la etiqueta debajo del desplegable) y usar flexbox sobre el elemento `div` que los contiene para ser capaz de cambiar el orden de los elementos en el `HTML`. Simplemente le tendrías que asignar un ID a cada elemento.

De esta manera, tu podrías usar el mismo CSS que estabas usando anteriormente y dará la sensación de que la etiqueta está por delante del select.

Tu ejemplo quedaría:

```css
#alReves{
  display: flex; /* Hacemos que nuestro contenedor sea flexbox */
}

#desplegable{
  order: 2; /* Indicamos que el desplegable esté el segundo */
}

#texto{
  order: 1; /* Indicamos que la etiqueta esté la primera */
}

select.valid + label{ 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="alReves">
  <select id="desplegable" class="valid">
    <option>Hola</option>
    <option>Adios</option>
  </select>
  <label id="texto">Hello</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Que manera más ingeniosa :)

Comment: Buena idea, yo añadiria el atributo `for` en el `label` para asociarlo con el `select`

Comment: @blonfu La verdad que desconocía este atributo pero he investigado un poco y la verdad que no le veo la utilidad que podría tener aquí.

Comment: Es un atributo básico en los formularios. Cuando el `label` engloba al control no hay problema `<label>texto<input type="text"></label>` pero si están separados es mejor ponerlo para asociar el `label` con el campo, sobre todo si no está en el orden esperado como es el caso. Además al pinchar sobre el `label` si tiene el `for` directamente coge el foco el campo (si es un _radiobutton_ o _checkbox_ se activa).

Comment: @blonfu Sí, pero en este caso es un `div` y no un formulario. He visto que se utiliza para formularios básicamente. Lo de que coge el foco también lo he leído pero sigo sin verle demasiada utilidad en este caso. Igual se me está escapando algo esencial y no me estoy dando cuenta.

Comment: Un `select` es un campo de formulario aunque no este dentro de una etiqueta `form`. Usar el `for` es sobre todo un tema de accesibilidad.

Comment: @blonfu Vale, muchas gracias por la información. La verdad que no sabía de la existencia de este atributo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49470/discussion-between-blonfu-and-error404).

Comment: @Error404 La propiedad `order` de los elementos flexibles por default tiene un valor de `0`. En lugar de declarar dos rule-sets, puedes hacerlo con uno solo, ya sea definiendo `order: -1;` en el elemento `label` u `order: 1;` en el `select`.

Comment: @Ricky Muchas gracias por añadir la aclaración aquí. Sin embargo, lo puse de este modo (poniendo el orden para cada elemento) para que se viera mucho más visualmente que estaba cambiando las posiciones de uno y otro elemento.