# Aplicar filtro css a contenedor padre sin afectar los hijos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Revisando en el sitio, veo que esta pregunta se ha echo anteriormente con regularidad, la solución que proponen es revertir la propiedad con los selectores `> *` Fuentes: [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43796/aplicar-css-a-un-elemento-padre) [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/como-aplicar-transformaciones-css3-a-un-elemento-padre-sin-afectar-los-elemento) [3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37084/c%C3%B3mo-seleccionar-el-elemento-anterior-a-otro-con-css)

Quisiera que el filtro `brightness` para oscurecer el color primario `primary-color`, no afecte al texto en blanco `text-white` en la sección `footer`.

Tengo una plantilla web en la que existe únicamente un color primario (aplicado a *navbars*, botones, *footers*, etc) y un secundario que por defecto siempre será gris.

Este color primario lo debo cambiar a petición por el usuario, tengo muchos usuarios, y para dar un poco de variedad a ese `primary-color`, aplico filtros CSS (como saturación para "avivar" un poco el tono, o brillo para aclarar u oscurecer el tono). Sé que no es la mejor forma y existen alternativas como LESS en CSS en la que puedo utilizar `@variables` para definir valores; lamentablemente el sitio está muy avanzado ya para pasarme a esta opción (A lo mejor en un futuro con más tiempo y conocimiento lo haga).

Usando estos filtros solo debo cambiar el valor heaxadecimal en `primary-color` y listo. (No estoy siendo perezoso, en serio me ahorra demasiado trabajo y tiempo).

Esto es lo que tengo actualmente.

```css
.primary-color{
background-color: #4285F4;
}

.primary-color .footer-copyright{
filter: brightness(50%);
}

.text-white{
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="page-footer font-small primary-color darken-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="mb-5 flex-center">
            <p class="text-center">Redes Sociales</p>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center text-white py-3 primary-color">© Copyright</div>

  </footer>
```

Y así es como quisiera que se vea:

[image: Imagen]

Comment: No estoy seguro si entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero tal vez podrías usar un position: absolute para el texto en blanco y así ubicarlo por encima del contenedor que estas oscureciendo.

Comment: Este selector `.primary-color > * .footer-copyright` es un poco raro y no seleccionará nada porque `.footer-copyright` es un hijo directo de `.primary-color` y al hacer `.primary-color > * .footer-copyright` entonces estás indicando que `.footer-copyright` debe ser al menos un nieto. Deberías indicar qué preguntas has utilizado como referencia en el sitio y explicar qué es lo que intentas hacer con el filtro y el código. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Hola y gracias por sus atentas observaciones, voy a modificar mi código para darme a entender mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te dicen los compañeros en los comentarios es muy cierto, por un lado usa `position: absolute`, preferiblemente en una clase aparte (como un "nieto").

Esto es lo que yo haría, cabe resaltar que las propiedades `top` y `right` de la clase `.text-white` tienen valores para ajustarlos al *snippet* de esSO, debes usar unos diferentes en tu sitio web, o bien asignarle un ancho fijo a ese DIV, aplicar un `left:50%` y luego con la propiedad `margin-left` le das un valor que sea la mitad del ancho del DIV.

O como gustes y sea acorde a tu necesidad. Suerte!

```css
.primary-color{
background-color: #4285F4;
}

.primary-color .footer-copyright{
filter: brightness(50%);
}

.text-white{
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
right: 45%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="page-footer font-small primary-color darken-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="mb-5 flex-center">
            <p class="text-center">Redes Sociales</p>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright py-3 primary-color">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="text-white">© Copyright</div>

  </footer>
```

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Te propongo otra opción mucho más simple y sencilla, sin necesidad de crear otro `div`.

Solo cambiando una propiedad de tu CSS:

```
filter: brightness(50%);
```

Por

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

```css
.primary-color {
  background-color: #4285F4;
}

.primary-color .footer-copyright {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text-white {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small primary-color darken-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-5 flex-center">
          <p class="text-center">Redes Sociales</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center text-white py-3 primary-color">© Copyright</div>

</footer>
```